# How to ignore namespaces in XPath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm having serious issues trying to understand the magic that is XPath.

Basically, I have some XML like so:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c/>
    </b>
</a>
```

Now, I want to count how many B's we have, without C's. This can be done easily with the following XPath:

```
count(*/b[not(descendant::c)])
```

Now the question is this simple: How do I do the same thing, while ignoring any namespaces?

I'd imagine it was something like this?

```
count(*/[local-name()='b']/[not(descendant::[local-name()='c'])])
```

But this is not correct.  What would be the equivalent XPath as I have above but that ignores namespaces?

Comment: If you're asking specifically about XPath 1.0, do please make this clear in your question. In XPath 2.0 and 3.0 you can write *:c to select elements with local name c in any namespace.

Comment: OP did tag the question explicitly as xpath-1.0, but I probably should have represented that in the title edit I made.  Fixed now.

Comment: Ok my bad. I assumed it was enough to tag the topic as xpath-1.0. I'll be sure to add that to the subject next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given XPath,

```
count(*/b[not(descendant::c)])
```

can be re-written to ignore namespaces as follows:

```
count(*[local-name()='b' and not(descendant::*[local-name()='c'])])
```

Note that it generally is better not to defeat namespaces but to work with them properly by assigning namespace prefixes and using them in your XPath expression.

Comment: Sweet, thank you! Had to spend a little more time wondering when the real scenario has multiple elements before this decision, but I got there in the end. And I hear you about the namespaces, but in this case we've validated the XML way before this part. This is basically just a code-behind check that we specifically do NOT want to be namespace dependant.